# Зачем два абсолютно идентичных [шейдера]?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Нашёл две подозрительно похожие метки:

- [shader](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shader) (112 вопросов)
- [шейдеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b) (36 вопросов)

Думаю их надо синонимизировать (в пользу чего, пока точно не знаю).

Comment: и в чём же их абсолютная идентичность?

Comment: Русской, конечно.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ в значении...

Comment: так оно без описания. Значение можно только из вопросов попробовать понять, на которые метку вешали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Готово:

```
updating post history, 132 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 114 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 107 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'shader': [shader] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 144
tag remapping of [шейдеры] and [shader] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
11 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
8 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym shader -> шейдеры was approved!
```